# redux toolkit dipatching buildercase twice actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

I am trying to figure out why during refresh does the dispatch action gets run twice and the endpoint is also been called twice.

This is my slice

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(fetchAppointments.pending, (state, action) => {
      state.loading = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchAppointments.fulfilled, (state, {payload}) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.total = payload.total;
      state.dates = payload.dates;
      state.data = payload.data;
    });
    builder.addCase(fetchAppointments.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.total = {};
      state.dates = [];
      state.data = {};
    });
  },
```

In my component I have it set up this way

```
  const { apptDates } = useSelector<AppState>((state: any) => {
    return {
      apptDates: state.appt
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchAppointments());
  }, [dispatch]);
```

Any ideas as to why the dispatch are called twice and the endpoint is call called twice in the network tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have React's `<StrictMode>` component in use, all `useEffect` will run twice in development mode. That's probably what is happening here.

Comment: Yup, that was it.   whoops lol